Can't find keyword using Playwright & Pyppeteer
When using all kinds of Python automation tools (such as Playwright and Pyppeteer), I can't seem to grab the "Continue with Google" button on https://dropbox.com/login. When I do this through the console like this:
const element = [...document.querySelectorAll('span,button,div,a')].find(el => el.textContent.includes('Doorgaan met Google'));

// Check if the element is found and click it
if (element) {
    element.click();
    console.log('Button clicked successfully!');
} else {
    console.error('Button not found!');
}

It finds and clicks the button in Chrome, but not in Firefox. In the programs I've written using Playwright and Pyppeteer, I couldn't find the button either (although sometimes literally just evaluating the same JS code).
Anyone know what this is caused by?

Sharing the content of your scripts would be useful.

Apparently the structure generated for FireFox is different from the structure generated for other browsers. This worked on FireFox for me:
document.querySelector(".L5Fo6c-bF1uUb").click()

In FireFox the button has this structure:
<div id="some_id_here" class="L5Fo6c-bF1uUb" tabindex="0"></div>

and no inner text. This is why your script did not find it in FireFox.

Thanks for the response, but it should still be possible to find:
<span class="nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-BPrWId">Doorgaan met Google</span>, no? Also how do you explain Playwright also not finding this despite running on Chrome?

@LLScheme the find function will find the first match. So whenever it fails to find your element, there are exactly two possible cases for failure. Either there was no match, or there was some other first match which was not the button. Therefore, your issue is that your way to select is vague (any text matches inside any other div will break your code) and it assumes a language, which may be set differently. I have English Google but Romanian IP address. When I load the page, it briefly shows the text in Romanian and switches to English. It may be the exact behavior in Playwright.

@LLScheme "Thanks for the response, but it should still be possible to find: Doorgaan met Google" No.In FireFox it's a div, not a span and has no inner text.

I see thanks. How would you suggest to tackle this problem? Since I would need this to work for other sites running OAuth as well so I can't simply select the specific div. About the span, if I click on the one I pasted in here that wouldn't work then? You would need the actual div that you put in your main comment?

@LLScheme there is no way around writing precise selectors. I would create a map of selectors where Dropbox_Google_Button would be the key and the collection of selectors the value, in our case you would have browser-based differentiation. Or, if that's unfeasible, then you could comma-separate your precise selectors, like selector1,selector2. If this answer pointed you to the right direction, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Is there no way to avoid this specification? Since most sites will have "Continue with Google" (or in a different language) as their button.

@LLScheme not really, especially if you may have multiple languages in use. You can always right-click the element you want to click on while the Dev Tools is open, hover on Copy and click on CSS Selector to copy the selector into your clipboard. I'm also not a fan of AI usage in development, but this looks like a data-entry task that very much looks like a task for AI if you have many sites.
